# Allow tag creation on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Currently, the site doesn't allow tag creation via the mobile site, presumably to avoid fat-fingering causing misspelt tags to be created.

I can see this policy making sense for Stack Overflow, which has a lot of traffic and involves people who ought to have access to desktops. But Travel.SE has less traffic, so it's easier to fix the odd mistake, and may involve people who don't have access to desktops.

Can we remove that rule for this site?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, this isn't something we can enable on a per-site basis. The mobile code (both website and app) don't even include any logic for handling new tags.

For now, a workaround might be to just use what tags you can, and leave a comment with your suggested new tags asking someone at a full-size computer to edit them in.

The way your question is phrased, the problem seems somewhat hypothetical. How often does this become an issue in practice? What tags have you found yourself wanting to create when you couldn't do so? I'm declining this for now, but I'll treat it the way we treat requests for MathJax formatting support on other sites: if you can provide us with examples where this has been a serious issue in the past, we could re-evaluate.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/41723/one-off-maori-lesson-in-auckland was the question. I wanted to create maori-language as a tag. I ended up accessing the desktop site via my phone to fix it.